# Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, deployment

I have created a .NET Core project with a SQL Server database in Windows 10, and I want to deploy it using the Nginx proxy on a virtual machine(Debian).

Which are the steps to follow to achieve that?

Comment: Why not run it on Windows server?

Comment: it's a research project

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has a well written documentation for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I didn't have much experience the first time I used this documentation. It was very easy to understand. Maybe this is a good start.